# How to validate the number of arrays input and validate blank arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, validation

Today i have a question that i would like to ask about. I am trying to figure out how to validate the number of array that i can enter. For example , i am trying to validate the max number of array entered as 6 . When i tried, it has some errors.

```
            if (productcode == null || productcode.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter array for productcode");
            }

            if (productcode[] > productcode[5])
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Array for productcode exceeded");
            }

            if (productcode == null || productcode.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter array for product code");

            }
            if (productdesc[] > productdesc[5])
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Array for productdesc exceeded");
            }

            if (quantity == null || quantity.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter array for quantity");
            }
            if(quantity[] > quantity[5])
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Array for quantity exceeded");
            }

            if (batchnumber == null || batchnumber.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter array for batch number");
            }
            if (batchnumber[] > batchnumber[5])
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Array for batch number exceeded");
            }

            if ( dod == null || dod.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter array for dod");
            }
            if (dod[] > dod[5])
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Array for dod exceeded");
            }

            if (unitcost == null || unitcost.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter array for unit cost");
            }
            if (unitcost[] > unitcost[5])
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Array for unitcost exceeded");
            }
```

Is this possible or are there any better way of doing ths?

Comment: `productcode[] > productcode[5]` doesn't compile

Comment: I think you mean `productcode.Length > 5` instead of `productcode[] > productcode[5]`.

Comment: No idea what you're trying to do. Sorry

Comment: `bool ValidateArraySize(object[] input, string arrayName) { // your logic here }`? Anyway it is unclear what you're asking. If you need help getting this to compile, explain what "some errors" you get. If you're looking for an alternative way to write what you show, explain what you expect it to do and what alternatives you have found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not *copy yourself*! Extract a method:

```
  private static Boolean showArrayErrorText(String name, Array array, int maxLength = 5) {
    if (array == null || array.Length <= 0) {
      MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Enter array for {0}", name));

      return false;
    }
    else if (array.Length > maxLength) {
      MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Array for {0} exceeded", name));

      return false;
    } 

    return true;
  }

...

  showArrayErrorText("productcode", productcode);
  showArrayErrorText("productdesc", productdesc);
  showArrayErrorText("batchnumber", batchnumber);
  ...
```

In case you want to *stop* validation after first error found:

```
   if (!showArrayErrorText("productcode", productcode))
     return;
   else if (!showArrayErrorText("productdesc", productdesc)) 
     return;
   else if (!showArrayErrorText("batchnumber", batchnumber)) 
     return;
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question but I think you need a product class and a product list:

```
public class Product 
{
    public string Code {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public int Quantity {get;set;}
    public int BatchNumber {get;set;}
    public string Dod {get;set;}
    public decimal UnitCost {get;set;}

}
```

The list:

```
var products = new List<Product>();
```

The validator:

```
public void Validate(List<Product> products)
{
    if (products == null || products.Length == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Too few products");
        return;
    }
    if (products.Length > 5)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Too many products");
        return;
    }
    // do something useful with the products
}
```